# JBoss start stuck on Weld service

Tags: java, jboss

After I began using OCI, sometimes the JBoss stuck when starting Weld service.

```
15:28:14,948 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment abena-ear.ear
15:32:59,961 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:d in state  RUN
15:32:59,965 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:d invoked while multiple threads active within it.
15:32:59,966 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:d aborting with 1 threads active!
15:32:59,967 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:d
15:32:59,970 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:c in state  RUN
15:32:59,974 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:c invoked while multiple threads active within it.
15:32:59,975 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:e in state  RUN
15:32:59,975 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:c aborting with 1 threads active!
15:32:59,977 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:c
15:32:59,978 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:e
15:32:59,987 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:f in state  RUN
15:32:59,988 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:f invoked while multiple threads active within it.
15:32:59,989 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:10 in state  RUN
15:32:59,989 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:f aborting with 1 threads active!
15:32:59,991 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:f
15:32:59,992 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:10 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
15:32:59,993 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:10 aborting with 1 threads active!
15:32:59,993 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:10
15:32:59,994 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:11 in state  RUN
15:32:59,995 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:11 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
15:32:59,996 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:11 aborting with 1 threads active!
15:32:59,998 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:11
15:33:00,011 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:12 in state  RUN
15:33:00,012 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff7f000101:-430b779d:55c4b259:12 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
```

On development environment most of the times JBoss starts without problems. But sometimes I see this error and I need to stop and start again JBoss.

On test/production environment it is happening often. Sometimes I need to stop and start again several times.

Looking to log we can see that it was stuck for more than 4 minutes before a WARN from Transaction Reaper.

Thanks for any help!

Solution: it stopped happening when I migrated to Wildfly 10.0.0.Final

Comment: It has probably something to do with the default 5min timeout. so probably a part of your business logic exceeds that timeout. its hard to guess what the cause could be.

Comment: @ChrisKo that's most probably it. [Here](https://mirocupak.com/enabling-long-deployments-on-wildfly/)'s an article describing how to fix it for those who might have the same problem without the ability to upgrade to Wildfly 10.